# Remove optional SignHere tab

Tags: docusignapi

I have an optional SignHere tab and I want to remove it.

To make the tab not optional I do the following, it works:

1. Retrieve the recipient tabs (api call)
2. Modify the optional value to 'true'
3. Modify the recipients tabs (api call)

I would also like to remove/hide the tab if I don't need it, but there's no visible flag to change.

Do I have to set the location to somewhere off-page? There has to be a better way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just delete/remove the tab from the document? https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Delete%20Tabs%20for%20a%20Recipient.htm?Highlight=delete%20tab

Comment: @Luis Scott -- please submit your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach is to delete/remove the tab from the document:

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Delete%20Tabs%20for%20a%20Recipient.htm?Highlight=delete%20tab

Comment: Thanks, works. Now I'm having a problem with recipientIDs in the url being called invalid.